# Reducing border width of Leaflet polygon

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, geojson

When adding a polygon to a Leaflet map, the border is quite wide (dark blue in image below). For maps of a wide area, this often obscures finer details of the map underneath.

**Is it possible to reduce the width of the border, while retaining the other default styling of the polygon?**

Currently I am creating the polygon from GeoJSON using

```
var boundary = { "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[....]}};
var poly = L.geoJson(boundary);
map.addLayer(poly);
```

[image: Map of Hoxton, London]

I am using Leaflet 0.7.3 (latest stable release). I'd be interested in solutions that change the style across all instances of leaflet maps, as well as ways to change it for a specific map.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please [read the Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path), which specifies a [weight](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-weight) option for paths, which you can [specify as an option to L.geoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson).

```
var poly = L.geoJson(boundary, { weight: 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks perfect. Could you modify your answer to include the code snippet in the answer - hyperlinks are prone to change or break over time.

Comment: @tmcw, do you know about how to specify no outline on polygons?

Comment: It's the first option in the linked documentation: `stroke: false`